# MuleSoft ESB Batch Transactions

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

Thanks is advance for any help. Here is the scenario that I am trying to recreate in Mulesoft.

1,500,000 records in a table. Here is the current process that we use.

Start a transaction.

delete all records from the table.

reload the table from a flat file.

commit the transaction.

in the end we need the file in a good state, thus the use of the transaction. If there is any failure, the data in the table will be rolled back to the initial valid state.

I was able to get the speed that we needed by using the Batch element < 10 minutes, but it appears that transactions are not supported around the whole batch flow.

Any ideas how I could get this to work in Mulesoft?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A little different workflow but how about:

- Load temp table from flat file
- If successful drop original table
- Rename temp table to original table name

You can keep your Mule batch processing workflow to load the temp table and forget about rolling back.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  The issue with a non-transactional solution is that I am not covered in all cases.  If there is a connection or server issue during the import this would leave the data in a bad state.  Whereas SQL server would see that the transaction was not completed on startup and roll it back.

Comment: I see what you mean. Inside Mule batch processing the "On Complete" phase gives you statistics on how many records succeeded or failed. You can use this to determine whether to swap out the temp table for the original or not. A bonus is that you can make a successful record dependent on not only writing to the db but also loading the file and even data validation.

Answer (score 0):

For this you might try the following:

- Use XA transactions (since more than one connector will be used,
  regardless of the use of the same transport or not)
- Enlist in the transaction the resource used in the custom Java code.

This also can be applied within the same transport (e.g. JDBC on the Mule configuration and also on the Java component), so it's not restricted to the case demonstrated in the PoC, which is only given as a reference.

Comment: Thanks Sanjeet.  I will give this a try and let you know.  I am a newbie so not sure about using custom Java code yet.

Comment: @Gonzo yes please try and do let me know if in case of any issues

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this article https://dzone.com/articles/passing-java-arrays-in-oracle-stored-procedure-fro

From temp table poll records.You can contruct array with any number of records. With 100K size will only involve 15 round trips in total.

To determine error records you can insert records in an error table but that has to be implemented in database procedure.